# Warum "eine Hausnummer nennen"?

Tags: etymology

Wenn man "eine Hausnummer nennt", gibt man [eine etwaige Größenordnung](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~eine%20Hausnummer%20nennen&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou) bzw. [grobe Schätzung](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Hausnummer) an.

Warum eine *Hausnummer*? Eine Hausnummer ist eigentlich sehr konkret. Frage ich jemanden nach seiner Hausnummer, finde ich das exakt richtige Haus.

Wieso wird Hausnummer hier für etwas Geschätztes verwendet?

Comment: Sagt man nicht eher ursprünglich "gib' mir mal eine ungefähre Hausnummer"? Und findet damit wenigstens die richtige Gegend, wo man hinwill?

Comment: reine Spekulation: das richtige Haus wohl schon, aber nicht notwendigerweise die richtige Wohnung (z.B. in einem Wohnblock)

Comment: Ist es wirklich so ein großer Unterschied zum engl. _ballpark (estimate)_? Auch hier geht es um eine ungefähre Schätzung. Die Hausnummer erlaubt eben noch nicht den Gegenstand, die Person etc. zu lokalisieren -- aber die Richtung stimmt.

Comment: Was @Ingmar gesagt hat. In Fällen, in denen ich auf Englisch *ballpark* sage, würde ich auf Deutsch *Hausnummer* sagen. Und nebenbei, wenn du von meiner Adresse nur die Hausnummer wüsstest, würdest du am falschen Haus klingeln.

Comment: Ich habe mich mal bezüglich Hausnummern gebildet: Anscheinend war es bis ca. 1850 zumindestens außerhalb von Grosstädten üblich, nicht *Strasse und Hausnummer*, sondern *(Stadtbezirk) und Hausnummer* als Adresse anzugeben. Die Hausnummer stellte also u.U. nur eine laufende Nummer der Gebäude in der Stadt dar und hatte überhaupt nichts mit seinem Standort zu tun - half also auch beim Suchen einer Gebäudes nicht besonders, ausser man hatte ein Register. Sollte das Idiom vor 1850 entstanden sein, muss man das mit beachten, wenn man eine Erklärung finden will.

Comment: Das "Wörterbuch der deutschen Umgangssprache" nennt "Hausnummer" auch als umgangssprachlichen Begriff für die *Regimentsnummer* in einer Armee (spätes 19. Jhd). Vielleicht ist ja das eine Spur. Regimenter sind zwar ziemlich gross, aber man weiss dann zumindestens ungefähr, wo einer hingehört.

Comment: Wenn wir schon beim Stöbern sind: Heinrich Heine [schlägt vor, "alle obskuren Autoren" _nach Hausnummern_ (sc. des jeweiligen Autors) zu zitieren](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/reisebilder-393/30). Damit könne man nämlich auch noch das abwegigste Zitat nachprüfen, da zumindest der Autor selber ein Exemplar seines Machwerks aufbewahren wird... übrigens ein schönes Beispiel dafür, dass "Hausnummer" im Sinne eines _pars pro toto_ für die genaue Adresse stehen kann.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Eine ähnliche Frage wurde vor einiger Zeit schon bei ["wer weiß was"](http://www.wer-weiss-was.de/t/hausnummer-anhaltspunkt/4335421) gestellt.

Zwei der Antworten dort behaupten sinngemäß, dass *Hausnummer* als Synonym für eine völlig willkürliche Zahl benutzt wurde und sich das irgendwann mal in Richtung "grobe Schätzung" entwickelt hat.

Interessanter finde ich aber den Hinweis auf das "Wörterbuch der deutschen Umgangssprache" von Küpper. Ich habe es nicht zur Hand und kann nur hoffen, dass [diese Quelle](http://umgangssprache_de.deacademic.com/11005/Hausnummer) es korrekt wiedergibt. In den dortigen Bedeutungen 8 und 9 steht Hausnummer seit ca. 1970 für etwas, was den persönlichen Vorstellungen entspricht oder jemandem angemessen ist (vgl. auch "das ist (nicht) meine Kragenweite"). Außerdem sei *Hausnummer* schon seit 1890 auch im Sinne von Schuhgröße verwendet worden. Es geht also jeweils um eine mit einer bestimmten Person verknüpfte Zahl, die symbolisch für die Vorstellungen dieser Person steht. Das zeigt sich auch an diesem frühen Fundstück (1974) aus der [Zeitschrift "Eulenspiegel"](https://books.google.de/books?id=y_E8AQAAIAAJ&q=%22als+hausnummer%22&dq=%22als+hausnummer%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjj_N-Y-qrNAhWHtRQKHQOTAJ8Q6AEIWTAI):

> Wir arbeiten zur Zeit an einer ganzen Latte überfälliger praktischer Dinge. Bloß als Hausnummer: Verbesserung der Materialversorgung, des Kunsthandels, der Nachwuchsförderung.

"Bloß als Hausnummer" wird hier offenbar benutzt im Sinne von "als Beispiel dafür, was ich meine", sogar ganz ohne quantitativen Bezug. In diesem Sinne könnte "Nennen Sie mir mal ihre/eine Hausnummer" gemeint gewesen sein als "Sagen Sie mir ihre Meinung (zu einer bestimmten Größe)", und von da dann allgemein weiter zur "groben Schätzung". Wobei ich den Ausdruck tatsächlich auch eher in Kontexten kenne, in denen es einen persönlichen Bezug gibt, also im Sinne von "was schätzt Du?".

Comment: Die Antwort gefällt mir inhaltlich sehr gut, zeigt aber auch die Grenzen der Herleitbarkeit. Wenn "Hausnummer" als Synonym für "Beispiel" verwendet werden kann, dann zerfasert der Begriff komplett. Oder anders gesagt: wenn das akzeptierter Sprachgebrauch ist, kann ich keine etymologische Verbindung mehr zum ursprünglichen Begriffsinhalt mehr erkennen - dann macht Etymologie praktisch keinen Sinn mehr. Das wäre dann beinahe schon ein Wort "ohne Herkunft".

Answer (score 3):

Ich kenne den Ausdruck eigentlich als "...ich brauche da eine *ungefähre* Hausnummer...". Danach fragt mich zum Beispiel der Taxifahrer, wenn er mich zumindestens in die richtige Gegend fahren will, auch wenn ich noch nicht ganz genau weiss, wo ich hin will und ihn erst weiter lotsen kann, sobald ich in der Nähe bin und vielleicht das Haus erkenne, wo ich hin will.

Ich könnte mir erklären, dass der Ausdruck so oder so ähnlich (nagut, mit Droschkenkutscher statt Taxifahrer...) entstanden ist und mit der Zeit das "ungefähr" sprachlich weggespart wurde.

Comment: Hm, aber ohne den Straßennamen nützt die Hausnummer nichts, und wenn man den kennt, kommt man (außer bei sehr langen Straßen) auch ohne Hausnummer schon in die richtige Gegend. Mich hat das jedenfalls noch nie ein Taxifahrer gefragt.

Comment: Auch ich finde den Erklärungsansatz nicht wirklich plausibel. Ich habe dazu meine Antwort ergänzt.

Comment: @Matthias - Mich fragt das der Taxifahrer ständig - Was wohl daran liegt, dass ich immer in sehr lange Strassen will.

Comment: Mich überzeugt das nicht. Vereinfacht gibt es zwei Fälle. Entweder weiß ich es genau, wo ich hin will oder nicht. Im ersten Fall gebe ich die exakte Hausnummer an, im zweiten Fall kann ich nicht mal eine Annahme stellen. Bei letzterem würde ich immer etwas in der Art "Fahr erstmal in die Straße XY und dann schauen wir weiter" sagen. Ein Taxifahrer hat mich übrigens noch nie nach einer "ungefähren" Hausnummer gefragt. Vielmehr glaube ich, dass das Wort "ungefähr" in der Redewendung nachträglich eingebaut wurde, als es bereits den Charakter einer Annäherung verinnerlicht hatte.

Comment: @Eml der Fahrer wird nicht alle Hausnummern im Kopf haben, er will nur ungefähr wissen welches Ende der Straße anzupeilen ist. Überzeugend ist die Antwort dennoch nicht gänzlich.

Answer (score 1):

Grobe Schätzung und exaktes Ergebnis widersprechen sich m.E. nicht. Nur ist die Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass das Ergebnis auch zutrifft, geringer. "Grobe Schätzung" betrifft m.E. die Methode, nicht die Präzision des Ergebnisses - wohl aber dessen "Validität".

Ein gutes Beispiel hierfür sind die beliebten, bis auf die Dezimalstelle "präzisen" Wahlprognosen. Es handelt sich um sehr exakte Angaben, deren Validität aber von der angewandten Hochrechnungsmethode und dem Ausgangssample (Mischung und Größe) abhängt.

Die Hausnummer **symbolisiert eine konkrete Ortsangabe in Form einer einfachen Ziffer**. Die Ziffer mag auf einer Schätzung beruhen, sie ist dennoch eine **konkrete Zahl**. Das Gegenteil wäre das Fehlen jeglicher Größenordnung, also nur "ziemlich gering" "ziemlich viel", "sehr groß", "extrem teuer". Es geht also darum, **eine bestimmte Ziffer in den Raum zu stellen**, selbst wenn unsicher ist, ob sie sich genau so realisieren wird. Ob der tatsächliche Wert wirklich dort oder nur im "Umkreis" liegt, ist nicht so wichtig, bzw. muss sich in der Zukunft erweisen. Aber mit einer Hausnummer steht ein fester Ort im Raum.

Damit ist einerseits das Risiko der **Falsifikation** verbunden ("*Wo steht das?*" - "*Irgendwo im vorderen Teil des Grundgesetzes.*" vs. "*In Artikel 20, glaube ich.*"), andererseits eine **Quantifizierung** ("*Wenn wir das Teil nicht austauschen, müssen Sie sich die nächsten Jahre auf ziemlich hohe Handwerkerrechnungen gefasst machen!*" vs. "*Rechnen Sie mal mit Reparaturkosten von mindestens 500 Euro alle vier bis fünf Jahre.*").

M.E. ist dabei gerade die Quantifizierung wichtig (oder, um im Bild zu bleiben: die Entfernung bis zum Punkt X, bzw. die Vergleichbarkeit mit anderen "Hausnummern" -> Entfernung zum alternativen Punkt Y).

EDIT:

Ich halte es unplausibel, anzunehmen, dass man früher oder auch heute noch reale Hausnummern zur Annäherung nutzen würde. Denn wenn ich das Ziel nicht genau bestimmen kann, dann werde ich **erst recht** keine Hausnummer nennen können, die dem Ziel nahe kommt. Stattdesssen bieten sich viele andere Zielbeschreibungen an, etwa nach markanten Punkten (Kirche, Hotel/Gaststätte, Apotheke, Markt, Brunnen, Standbild, Palais, Handwerker). Die Nennung einer Hausnummer setzt bereits voraus, dass ich den ungefähren Wertebereich kenne, also die wahrscheinlich höchste Hausnummer, und innerhalb dieses Bereichs auswähle. Und selbst wenn man den Wertebereich kennen würde, hülfe das überhaupt nichts, wenn (wie zB in Berlin) die Straße nach einem anderen Schema als erwartet nummeriert ist, zB rechte Straßenseite aufsteigend, linke Straßenseite absteigend nummeriert - das Haus mit der höchsten Nummer steht dann gegenüber der Nr. 1, und die "goldene Mitte" ist in Wahrheit ein "Extremwert" - nämlich am anderen Ende der Straße gelegen).

Comment: Wenn Du in Berlin jmd. besuchen willst, dann bist Du mit der exacten Hausnummer oft erst grob informiert. Da wohnen vielleicht mehr Leute, als in einem kleinen Dorf auf dem Land. Es gibt nicht selten mehrere Hinterhöfe und dementsprechend mehrere Quergebäude und Seitenflügel. Für Zeitungs-, Paket- und Postzustellung oder Handwerker ist die Hausnummer also erst mal eine grobe Näherung. Für's Taxi, das nicht reinfährt, ist die Hausnummer aber exact genug.

Answer (score -3):

1. Es gibt keine Dezimalstellen bei Hausnummern
2. Je nach Hausnummer kann man abschätzen wie teuer das Haus an der Hausnummer ist.
3. Der Ausdruck ist umgangssprachlich. Geben Sie mir mal eine Hausnummer klingt nicht korrekt. Aber, gib mir mal 'ne Hausnummer klingt korrekt.

Comment: Was die Existenz oder Nichtexistenz einer Dezimalstelle mit der Frage zu tun hat, erschließt sich mir leider nicht. Wenn ich genau 6 Brötchen kaufe, habe ich keine Dezimalstelle angegeben und mich trotzdem sehr genau geäußert, wenn ich es erzähle. Auch der zweite Punkt ist mir ein bisschen schleierhaft.

Comment: @tofro ist doch offensichtlich wie der Teil der Antwort gemeint ist. Wenn 500 Brötchen etwa 99,9 Groschen kosten, interessiert mich der Bruchteil eher weniger. Der zweite Punkt ist mir auch schleierhaft.